# Installing Full Text Search on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I can't for the life of me install full text search on my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

Every installer I have tried shows me this:

[Feature selection only shows Replication under features http://www.vme2-server.co.uk/images/sql.jpg](http://www.vme2-server.co.uk/images/sql.jpg)

I've tried:

- SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe
- SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe
- SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

The SQL Server is reporting a version of 10.52.4000.0

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Full text search, you need the 'Advanced Services' edition of SQL Server Express 2008, which can be obtained at [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1842)

However, you need to uninstall the current version first.

Comment: He mentioned that he has tried SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe, which is the Advanced Services edition. I myself have tried adding Full-Text Search using this installer, but it is simply not available. Perhaps Full-Text Search is only available in the Standard and/or Enterprise editions... Thanks Microsoft!